# OAuth2: No login dialog after log out, direct log in of last user

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth-2.0

I am building a flutter app that needs the user to authenticate against an identity provider in order to user the app.

I am using the package [simple_auth_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_auth_flutter) to do the authentication stuff. So far this works as expected: When clicking on the log in button, the users is queried for its credentials and after passing the correct credentials I get a valid token.

I only got an issue, when the user logs out from the identity provider. When the user clicks on the log in button he gets automatically logged in without querying for the current users credentials.

While logging out I delete the token from within the package and I revoke the token on identity providers side.

Any idea what could be the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OIDC based Identity Providers issue a session cookie when you login. This is what enables single sign on across multiple apps.

To force a new login prompt, logout typically needs to send an [End Session Request](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/endsession.html) so that this cookie gets removed.

My [Android sample code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/authguidance/basicmobileapp/plumbing/oauth/logout) does this, though I am using different libraries. Not sure if Flutter has end session support?

Also worth being aware that some identity providers require vendor specific messages.

Comment: Can confirm that this is the reason why it behaves like this. Now looking for a way to clear cookies in flutter. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SebastianK I'm stumbling over this issue right now - did you find a solution on how to clear the cookies in the embedded browser? Can you share your solution, please?

Comment: @Christian Not really sure, since it was some time ago. But If I remember correctly, there was some vendor specific stuff needed that is not really OAuth2 standard. The issue was not related to cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my flutter app using Firebase and Microsoft as identity provider. I solved the issue by using the "prompt" parameter within the authentication request. Below you can see my code for oAuth authentication with Microsoft.

```
await FirebaseAuthOAuth().openSignInFlow(
    "microsoft.com",
    ["email openid profile offline_access"],
    {
      'tenant': 'your tenant id',
      'clientId': 'your client id',
      'prompt': 'login'
    },
  );
```

Also see the Microsoft documentation where the "prompt" parameter is described in detail with all the supported values (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc).

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed**

When you logout on Firebase you are only clearing the app's state not the browser. One possible solution is to check if your provider offers a logout endpoint which you can call in your app during logout to invalidate the browser cookies. Microsoft is an example of a provider offering this.

The user data is attached with the provider session.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-a-sign-out-request

BEST SOLUTION:
User? user =
await firebaseAuthOAuth.openSignInFlow(provider, scopes, parameters);

Make sure parameters has a prompt key with an applicable value mentioned here: Fixed:

User? user =
await firebaseAuthOAuth.openSignInFlow(provider, scopes, parameters);

Make sure parameters has a prompt key with an applicable value mentioned here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-the-sign-in-request

The only one I got to work to an acceptable criteria is:
'prompt': 'select_account'

My provider, scopes, and parameters:
'microsoft.com', ['email'], {'prompt': 'select_account'}

The only one I got to work to an acceptable criteria is:
'prompt': 'select_account'

My provider, scopes, and parameters:
'microsoft.com', ['email'], {'prompt': 'select_account'}