# OAuth 2 logout via browser

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, logout

I have been reading the OAuth spec but am struggling to understand something about logging out.

Should I wish to sign out from a web app, does the spec provide a URL I can redirect a user to, that deletes their session including issued cookies?

I have found some docs that specify an endpoint I can make a `DELETE` request to, which revokes my tokens, but this does not revoke issued cookies?

I am imaging something like `${issuer}/v1/logout` that when opened in the browser, ends the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Open Id Connect there is an end session endpoint for this, though support varies between vendors. Here is a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176108/oauth2-no-login-dialog-after-log-out-direct-log-in-of-last-user) I posted earlier.

What software are you using for the Authorization Server?

Comment: Cool - Okta does logout in the standard way - you have to format the url and send the id token - as described [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-users-out/react/sign-out-of-okta/).